# Why does my iframe sometimes initially load the Return URL page before the DocuSign form has been signed?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, docusignapi

For my Next.js application, I'm embedding a DocuSign form using an iframe. At times when I visit the page where that form exists, I'll sometimes see the Return URL page (which I should only be redirected to in the iframe after having signed the form) when the page initially loads. After a few seconds, the correct page with the form loads in the iframe.

This issue does not occur when first visiting the form page. This typically happens after I return to home page (or visit any other page) without having signed the form and then return to the form page. Has anyone else who worked with embedding DocuSign forms using an iframe experienced this issue? If so, could you please explain how you were able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the envelope is locked. Instead of getting an error you get redirected back.
Normally, that will happen when you already signed.
It's also possible the URL you generated has expired. You have to generate it when the user click, not ahead of time, it expires within a few minutes.
Using an iframe can cause problems. What is the reason you use an iframe?

Comment: I'm using an iframe because the product owner doesn't want users to leave the application and be redirected to an external site to sign the waiver; embedded signing with iframe meets that requirement.

At the moment, a new form isn't being generated ahead of time. A brand-new form is generated once a user visits the waiver page.

Comment: you said that "This typically happens after I return to home page (or visit any other page) without having signed the form and then return to the form" suggesting to me that it was generated first, users clicked here and there, and then went back to it. or am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps I could have worded what you quoted above better. But yes, you missed the word following the last word you quoted (_i.e._, form **page**). Users aren't returning to that specific form, but to the page that would contain a form. At the moment, a new DocuSign form is generated once the page that contains the iframe is visited. So if they leave that page and return, a new form would have been generated. My confusion is why sometimes the Return URL page loads initially sometimes when the form wasn't signed in the first place, especially if a new form would have been generated.

Comment: and you say it's completely random? sometimes it works and sometimes not? there's no difference you can find?

Comment: maybe different users? or different documents? do you use a template?

Comment: No, it's not completely random. The aren't any issues when a user visits the form page for the very first time. Only if they visit the form page and don't sign the form, leave the page, and then return to the form page (where a new form is generated) does the issue occur of the Return URL page loading initially before a form is loaded again. And yes, I use a template.

Comment: Will need to see your code to help further.